# Dragging layers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, z-index, draggable, layer

I have two layers (DIVs) with different Z-index (1&2) on my screen.
I would like to be able to drag the lower layer (the one with z-index: 1) using jQuery.
How would I achieve that? HOw to pass the mouse movement and clicks to the lower layer?

Comment: Is the problem that you want mouse events that your z-indexed 2 div is capturing to be passed on to the z-indexed 1 div that is below it? Is the z-indexed 1 div a container for the z-indexed 2 div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily set a DIV to be draggable using jQuery UI.  Simply call

```
$("#mydiv").draggable();
```

The z-index will be whatever you give the DIV in your CSS.  Make sure you set a position attribute on both DIV's (either absolute or relative, it doesn't matter).  If you want to pass the drag event to the bottom layer, capture the event for the top layer and then use .trigger() to pass it along, as below.

```
$("#top").mousedown(function(event){
    $("#bottom").trigger(event);
});
```

You should probably also add some code to check that, on the mousedown of the top layer, the mouse is actually over the lower layer.

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I am looking for, I already knew both. My intention is to drag/move the "lower layer" with the mouse. If another DIV is over that layer, then there is no chance to move the lower layer, I am looking forward to find a way to pass the mouse click/movement to the lower layer and being able to drag that one.